# Document working with cite package, but not with natbib package

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, cite-package

I am trying to use the `natbib` style in order to cite references by author and year.

Using the tex and bib example [here](http://amath.colorado.edu/documentation/LaTeX/reference/faq/bibstyles.html) I am able to create a pdf file using the `cite` package.

`mydocuments.tex`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{cite}

\author{John Doe} \title{Sample Document}

\begin{document} \maketitle

\section{Introduction}

According to the handbook of van Leunen \cite{vanleunen}, this paragraph---and certainly this section---should be longer than one sentence.

\bibliographystyle{plain}   % (uses file "plain.bst")

\bibliography{myrefs}       % expects file "myrefs.bib"
\end{document}
```

`myrefs.bib`

```
@book{vanleunen,    title = "A Handbook for Scholars",

   author = "Mary-Claire van Leunen",

   publisher = "Knopf",

   year = "1979"   

}
```

When I switch to the `natbib` package (and the bibliography style `plainnat`), I get the error.

```
Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.
```

`mydocuments.tex`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document} \maketitle

\section{Introduction}

According to the handbook of van Leunen \cite{vanleunen}, this paragraph---and certainly this section---should be longer than one sentence.

\bibliographystyle{plain}   % (uses file "plain.bst")

\bibliography{myrefs}       % expects file "myrefs.bib"
\end{document}
```

What is wrong with the bib file in the example, and how do I format it for `natbib` please?

Comment: i think we need more than you've given us; a minimal example of the failure would help; this should be a complete, compilable document (so you need to provide a micro-.bib-file as well, introduced by a filecontents environment).  (afaict, from what you say, it _should_ be working...)

Comment: The example is in the web page that I have linked to. The files are literary there, all that needs to be done is copy and paste the contents.

Other than that, I am honestly at loss on what you're asking.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). More details on what we mean by Minimal Example can be found here: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228

Comment: It sounds like you LaTeX'ed (and BibTeX'ed) your document first with a different bibliography style (and the `cite` citation management package) and, more recently, have switched to `natbib` and `plainnat`. If that's the case, you may want to delete all "auxilliary" files and *then* rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: Thanks Mico, yours is a more complete answer :) Do you mind reposting it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct?

Comment: Thanks, but I'll suggest that @tochecz update and expand the existing answer so that it may be upvoted and check-marked. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you switch from the `cite` package to the `natbib` package, it is necessary to delete `.aux` and `.bbl` files since they contain the non-`natbib` information and the package complains about it.

Note that the two packages hardly work together, you have to choose.

Comment: Please edit your answer to state explicitly that, when switching to the `natbib` citation management package and the `plainnat` bibliography style, it's also necessary to (a) no longer load the `cite`package and (b) remove the `\bibliographystyle{plain}` directive? The reason I ask is that there's a new "answer", which claims there's some ambiguity in your answer with regard to coexistence of the `cite` and `natbib` packages. (It would have been better if the new "answer" had been posted as a comment under your answer, but I guess the user doesn't have sufficient rep yet to leave comments.)

Answer (score 0):

In case you use {cite} package, it is better to remove {natbib} and vice versa. There is no compatibility between the two packages.

Comment: The accepted answer seems to suggest that it's possible to use them together.

Comment: @Null - Where in the text of the accepted answer do you find this claim?

Comment: @Null I don't know where in "switch to `natbib`" you read "add `natbib`" or "keep `cite`" :-) Anyway, I clarified the answer.